# What is the difference between "do you know where" and "where is"?

Tags: difference, questions

I cannot understand the difference between these two sentences about the communication between two people.

> 1) Do you know where my son is?
>
> 2) Where is my son?

What is the difference?

Comment: What firstly comes to mind is that "do you know?" is a yes or no question, but the answer to "where?" is a location.

Comment: yes that's right. I don't think before ask this question

Comment: @MARamezani You can write an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where is my son?

This question expects that you (the person I'm asking) know the answer. It's a little more complicated than that, though:

- You might not know, but I am implying that you *should* know.
- You might not know, but I might be a panicked parent who (irrationally) demands answers from you anyway.
- I might be asking a whole group of people. Many of them won't know, but I'm assuming or hoping that *someone* will.

> Do you know where my son is?

This leaves open the possibility that the answer is "no, I don't know". However, if you do know, it is still expected that you will tell me! If I ask this and you just answer "yes", I will think you are being deliberately troublesome.

In other words, this is an **indirect** way of asking the same thing. Indirect questions are generally more polite in English. That does not mean that "Where is my son?" is *rude*; it's just not quite as polite.

---

**EDIT:** As supercat's comment below so rightly points out, this question of politeness depends a lot on the context. If you *should* know where my son is (e.g. I've come to pick him up from your house), I would say to you, "Where is my son?" (Okay, I'd probably use his *name*, but that's beside the point.)

If, instead, I said, "Do you know where my son is?", you would have good reason to think that I was being sarcastic: I am implying that you are negligent, and so you might possibly answer "no" to my question!

Comment: I'd say that "where is my son" would actually be more polite than "do you know" in cases if asking someone whose failure to know instantly would constitute dereliction of duty; "do you know" is more polite in cases where the answer could plausibly be "no", but not when it shouldn't.

Comment: @supercat: Good point. A *very* good point, in fact; I'll edit that in.